# How to set up searchable multiple attributes for associated models for Sunspot search on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I have some models with relations as follows:

Order has many order_items (model OrderItem);

Order belongs to one vendor(model User) which has associated model Company.

And I want to make these full-text searchable based on Order:

1) OrderItem's attributes: name, description
2) vendor's company name

Then I set up the searchable attributes like this:

```
searchable do
... 
text :order_items do
  order_items.map { |item| item.name item.description }    # 1
end  

text :vendor do
  vendor.company.name  # 2
end
```

Both rows #1 and #2 will report as errors when do re-indexing.

So, please help how to write codes for both cases.
Thanks.

Comment: and in which model you have added this searchable block?

Comment: In Order model, as I want to do search by order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write searchable methods on class and instance methods of the model.  Do something like the following:

```
class Order

  searchable do
    text :order_items_search
    text :vendor_search
  end

  def order_items_search
    self.order_items.map{|item| item.name + ',' + item.description}.join(',')
  end

  def vendor_search
    self.vendor.company.name
  end
end
```